# Firebase/Facebook Authentication - OAuthException - Code 190

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

I've been implementing Firebase authentication in my Android app and have got it working easily & successfully (signed in debug) for different authentication providers such as Google, however Facebook will not play ball.

I'm consistently receiving a com.google.firebase.FirebaseException when trying to authenticate with Facebook. I'm using the example from the [firebase/quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android) auth app on github. As you can see from the output below, the Facebook authentication is successful and a valid access token. however when I pass the token to Firebase to authenticate, the aforementioned exception is thrown.

```
06-14 00:42:24.704 13275-13275/com.cmpdhoug.logintesting I/FacebookLogin: facebook:onSuccess:com.facebook.login.LoginResult@427332f8
06-14 00:42:24.714 13275-13275/com.cmpdhoug.logintesting I/FacebookLogin: Access token details: {AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[user_friends, email, public_profile]}
06-14 00:42:24.714 13275-13275/com.cmpdhoug.logintesting I/FacebookLogin: Token: EAADk2AXUei8BAESARAsZAOCQoZBo1KoLD6GDMDiNUX7U6o92sRZAG5hJN4426JqOYz5p4mYb8yavpTrHlJpoXp7mkCyZCLZAxYy4uSwBC4tK8wbrjccZBkOOS5tgoAbbq0IZBvXVwMV5OUdW1LHMj8PbCMznSzlLageUbpW96Dpa5wk7zVVwFVnsXJZA6flmV98l669VWIkizUpd6OYpeMc4d82JUexPSrYZD
06-14 00:42:24.714 13275-13275/com.cmpdhoug.logintesting I/FacebookLogin: Acc ID: 107700652990130
06-14 00:42:24.714 13275-13275/com.cmpdhoug.logintesting I/FacebookLogin: App ID: 251616461879855
06-14 00:42:24.714 13275-13275/com.cmpdhoug.logintesting I/FacebookLogin: Expires: Sat Aug 13 00:19:00 BST 2016
06-14 00:42:24.714 13275-13275/com.cmpdhoug.logintesting I/FacebookLogin: Last Refresh: Tue Jun 14 00:42:24 BST 2016
06-14 00:42:24.714 13275-13275/com.cmpdhoug.logintesting I/FacebookLogin: Permissions: [user_friends, email, public_profile]
06-14 00:42:24.714 13275-13275/com.cmpdhoug.logintesting I/FacebookLogin: handleFacebookAccessToken:EAADk2AXUei8BAESARAsZAOCQoZBo1KoLD6GDMDiNUX7U6o92sRZAG5hJN4426JqOYz5p4mYb8yavpTrHlJpoXp7mkCyZCLZAxYy4uSwBC4tK8wbrjccZBkOOS5tgoAbbq0IZBvXVwMV5OUdW1LHMj8PbCMznSzlLageUbpW96Dpa5wk7zVVwFVnsXJZA6flmV98l669VWIkizUpd6OYpeMc4d82JUexPSrYZD
06-14 00:42:25.344 13275-13275/com.cmpdhoug.logintesting I/FacebookLogin: signInWithCredential:onComplete:false
06-14 00:42:25.344 13275-13275/com.cmpdhoug.logintesting W/FacebookLogin: signInWithCredential
                                                                          com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occured. [ Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: {"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token signature.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"Euly77Ri59w"}} ]
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacq.zzbN(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacn$zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacy.zzbO(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacy$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzact$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

The Facebook [errors page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#errors) would suggest a problem with the Access Token or Login Status, however the output confirms Log in is successful and the Access Token is fine. I've also confirmed the tokens validity using the Facebook Access Token [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/), entering the token in the output.

I'm hitting brick walls with everything I try, i searched SO thoroughly and tried a lot of different solutions, Googled for hours but not getting anywhere.

FacebookLoginActivity is launched from an intent within MainActivity. Android code for FacebookLoginActivity:

```
package com.cmpdhoug.logintesting;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

/**
 * Demonstrate Firebase Authentication using a Facebook access token.
 */
public class FacebookLoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "FacebookLogin";

    private TextView mStatusTextView;
    private TextView mDetailTextView;

    // [START declare_auth]
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    // [END declare_auth]

    // [START declare_auth_listener]
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    // [END declare_auth_listener]

    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);

        // Views
        mStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        mDetailTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail);
        findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_signout).setOnClickListener(this);

        // [START initialize_auth]
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // [END initialize_auth]

        // [START auth_state_listener]
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.i(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.i(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(user);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        };
        // [END auth_state_listener]

        // [START initialize_fblogin]
        // Initialize Facebook Login button
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_login);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.i(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                Log.i(TAG, "Access token details: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().toString());
                Log.i(TAG,"Token: " + AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
                Log.i(TAG,"Acc ID: " + AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId());
                Log.i(TAG,"App ID: " + AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getApplicationId());
                Log.i(TAG,"Expires: " + AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getExpires());
                Log.i(TAG,"Last Refresh: " + AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getLastRefresh());
                Log.i(TAG,"Permissions: " + AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions());
                AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.i(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(null);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.i(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(null);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        });
        // [END initialize_fblogin]
    }

    // [START on_start_add_listener]
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
    // [END on_start_add_listener]

    // [START on_stop_remove_listener]
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
    // [END on_stop_remove_listener]


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    // [START auth_with_facebook]
    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.i(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);
        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        showProgressDialog();
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(FacebookLoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }
    // [END auth_with_facebook]

    public void signOut() {
        mAuth.signOut();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

        updateUI(null);
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        if (user != null) {
            mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.facebook_status_fmt, user.getDisplayName()));
            mDetailTextView.setText(getString(R.string.firebase_status_fmt, user.getUid()));

            findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_login).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_signout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);
            mDetailTextView.setText(null);

            findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_login).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_signout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_facebook_signout:
                signOut();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.cmpdhoug.logintesting">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
        <activity android:name=".EmailPassword">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".GoogleSignIn">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FacebookLogin">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FacebookLoginActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hey ,how did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Shruti Hi, I was unable to resolve the issue. In the end I gave up and created a new project from scratch.

Comment: That's sad.Thanks for your reply but I got my mistake;I was using different Facebook App Id in the Manifest.

Answer (score 3):

Can you check your Facebook App ID & Secret settings in Firebase Console are correct? If so, please file a bug for Firebase Authentication at https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely entering wrong app credentials in Firebase account. Try copying them once again.
**Care**:- Facebook hides the app secret for you in settings tab. Click on show and then copy it to your firebase account, else it will show the same error.

Comment: I made the mistake of just copying the dots that conceal the app secret instead of just clicking reveal & copying the actual text! cheers! for any one else dont be lazy & make the same stupid mistake I did