# Firebase Account Merging with different providers

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently able to login with the following providers: Google, Facebook, and Twitter. Also linking two accounts with `linkcredentials()` seems to be working as intended as well:

Ideally I want following scenario:

1. Login Facebook
2. Logout Facebook
3. Login Google with same e-mail as Facebook
4. Automatically account to be linked with Facebook.

OR

1. Login Google
2. Logout Google
3. Login Facebook with same e-mail as Google
4. Automatically account to be linked with Google.

The above scenario was founded in offerup website, and I wanted to implement it in the same way. However, this will not work with `linkcredentials()` as one account will be already linked to the other provider.

I do want to use the Firebase Auth library, but I am not sure in which direction I need to go to make above scenario possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801098/firebase-facebook-authentication-oauthexception-code-190 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900425/android-firebase-authentication-for-google-signin-fails

Comment: Please provide the code you have written so far.